# Изменение входных параметров java процедурой

Tags: java, процедуры

В связи с вопросом [`Java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for`](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1027020/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for), возник вопрос: Каким же образом `java` процедура (функция, не возвращающая значение) может изменить значения входных параметров? Функцию использовать не могу, т. к. надо изменить значения нескольких входных параметров. (желательно привести пример для процедур с теми же заголовками, что и на [`Java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for`](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1027020/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for), если конечно вообще такое возможно).

Answer (score 5):

Если передать в *процедуру* ссылку на объект, то **заменить** значение объекта нельзя, так как передаётся **копия ссылки** на объект. Сколько не присваивай этой копии ссылку на другой объект, оригинальная ссылка не изменится.

Поэтому код:

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void functionThatChangesParam( String arg ) {
        arg = "After";
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
         String toChange = "Before";
         System.out.println( toChange );
         functionThatChangesParam( toChange );
         System.out.println( toChange );
    }
}
```

Выведет:

```
Before
Before
```

А вот **изменить** объект по ссылке можно. В Java нет модификатора `const`, как в C++. Поэтому все ссылки на объекты неконстантные. И методы не делятся на константные/неконстантные. Вы можете передать в *процедуру* ссылку на объект, и эта *процедура* вызовет `сеттер`, например, чем **изменит** состояние аргумента. Другой пример - массивы. Вы передаёте ссылку на массив, а *процедура* заменяет какой-либо элемент в массиве, то есть **изменяет** сам массив, но не **заменяет** его другим массивом.

Например, код:

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void setElementOfArray( String[] args ) {
        args[0] = "After";
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
         String[] arr = new String[1];
         arr[0] = "Before";
         System.out.println( arr[0] );
         setElementOfArray( arr );
         System.out.println( arr[0] );
    }
}
```

выведет:

```
Before
After
```

PS. Процедур и функций в Java нет. Есть методы класса и статические методы класса. В ответе под "процедурой" понимается любой из методов.

Answer (score 3):

В Java параметры передаются **по значению**. Это значит, что изменения формального параметра никаким образом не отображаются на выражении, которое было использовано в качестве аргумента.

Пример: если у вас есть функция:

```
void change(int x) { x = 10; }
```

— и вы вызываете её так:

```
change(5);
```

вы ведь не считаете, что значение константы 5 должно срочно поменяться на 10?

(В других языках, например, C++ или C#, есть возможность передать в функцию параметр *по ссылке* — но не в Java.)

Вы должны делать по-другому. Самый правильный путь — пусть функция *возвращает* созданный объект.

```
int change(int x) { x = 10; return x; }

int z = 5;
z = change(z);
// здесь z == 10
```

Другая возможность — воспользоваться тем, что вам в функцию приходит не deep copy, а лишь shallow copy. То есть, к вам приходит ссылка на реально существующий объект, и несмотря на то, что подмена ссылки не видна снаружи, изменения в объекте будут видны:

```
class Parameters
{
    public int x;
}

void change(Parameters p) { p.x = 10; }

Parameters p = new Parameters();
p.x = 5;
change(p);
// тут p.x == 10
```

Можно даже воспользоваться грязным трюком, и заставить функцию `change` принимать массив из одного элемента как аргумент. Но лучшей альтернативой всё равно является возврат значения:

```
class Parameters
{
    public int x;
}

Parameters InitFromOtherParameters(Parameters p)
{
    Parameters q = new Parameters();
    q.x = p.x * 2;
    return q;
}

Parameters old = new Parameters();
old.x = 5;
Parameters current = InitFromOtherParameters(old);
// current.x == 10;
```

Comment: @VladD @atwice ArrayList<String> незаполненные и переданные на вход метода будут изменены в результате выполнения метода и если они затем поступают на вход другой функции, то эта функция получит на вход уже измененные ArrayList-ы? (то же самое, что и с массивами?)

Comment: @ivan89: Да. Изменения в _содержимом_ объекта видны по выходу из процедуры.