# Вопросы от начинающего

Tags: java

Я совершенно новичок и только недавно начал изучать программирование с Java. По ходу дела возникают скорее всего простейшие вопросы.

Скрин 1. Как сделать чтобы в методе "пробный метод" было несколько передаваемых параметров, не один икс, а еще какие нибудь? Вроде можно прописать в круглых скобках еще строку, например `y`, который будет приплюсовывать другую фразу, но как тогда направлять `name` на `x`, а `sername` на `y`? Или я подозреваю, что так делать совсем нельзя и нужно писать отдельный метод для `y`.

Скрин 2. Почему так нельзя сделать и в чем разница, если все мои переменные и т.п. написаны внутри класса, а не внутри метода `main`, прошу объяснить. То, что метод `main` - это входная точка каждой программы, я понял, и с него все начинается.

Вопрос 3. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, литературу, которая действительно поможет начать. Вроде везде **Философия Java** советуют.

[image: Скрин 1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените Ваши скрины реальным кодом, вставленным в вопрос. Чтобы блок текста отображался как код, он должен быть отделен пустыми линиями и иметь отступ слева не менее 4 пробелов

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/204271)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что очень общий и не содержит кода в виде текста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
  Можно передать так до 65к+ аргуентов или использовать [varargs](https://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs) для передачи неопределенного количества аргументов одного типа

```
public String method(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1 + s2;
}
```

2. Выражения должны находится внутри методов, но определения переменных могут находит внутри классов и внутри методов.
   Если вы хотите указать начальное значение для переменной то укажите его при объявлении или присвойте значение в конструкторе класса.

#### Update

То что вы в методе `probniyMethod` присваиваете `x` новое значение, сделает его видимым только внутри метода. [Похожий вопрос.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/225597/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9)
Если вам нужно изменить несколько аргументов функцией, оберните их в класс, реализуйте `getters` и `setters`.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Data d = new Data("s1", "s2")

        System.out.println(d.getS1());
        System.out.println(d.getS2());

        changeData(d);

        System.out.println(d.getS1());
        System.out.println(d.getS2());
    }

    private static changeData(Data data) {
        data.setS1(data.getS1() + ", changed")
        data.setS2(data.getS2() + ", changed")
    }
}

class Data {
    private String s1;
    private String s2;

    public Data(String s1, String s2) {
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
    }

    public String getS1() {
        return s1;
    }

    public void setS1(String s) {
        s1 = s;
    }

    public String getS2() {
        return s2;
    }

    public void setS2(String s) {
        s2 = s;
    }
}
```

P.S. Почитайте про **наследование**, **полиморфизм**, **инкапсуляцию**

Comment: Аргументы передал, а как теперь направить одну строку на один аргумент, а вторую на другой? (т.е. sername на x, а name на новый аргумент y), как правильно это записать?

Comment: @jewbaka обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

> Почему так нельзя сделать и в чем разница, если все мои переменные и
>   т.п. написаны внутри класса, а не внутри метода main, прошу объяснить.

В методе main переменные локальные для данного метода.
В классе переменные относятся к классам. Когда вы создаете экземпляр класса, метод относится к экземпляру, объекту вашего класса.

Философию Java читайте после более простых книг. На начальном этапе обучения вам будет сложно понять те или иные концепции. Возьмите что-нибудь попроще. Не стоит сразу читать труды именитых ученых. Вам будет сложно понять их мысли. Если вы поймете, то вам трудно будет общаться с рекрутами, и техническим персоналом, которые  этого не понимают.